# Uploading multiple binaries simultaneously to itunesconnect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode8, application-loader

I have a multiple lite and paid apps and it gets annoying to submit a binary and wait for it to finish processing before doing the next one every update. I heard you can submit multiple binaries at the same time in application loader, but have yet to find out how.

> Is it actually possible to do this? Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane

Brilliant tuturial by raywenderlich on how to use it  https://www.raywenderlich.com/116065/fastlane-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You could write a shell script to build, sign, and upload your app to iTunesConnect. (You mentioned in a comment you have 40 apps to upload, if that's the case you should definitely, definitely, automate the whole process like this)

I won't cover building and signing (plenty online how to do this via shell script/terminal commands), but uploading to iTunes connect uploading isn't as well known about or documented.

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support/altool --upload-app -f "signed .ipa file" -t ios -u username -p password`

Your script could in succession for each app you need to upload. Or heck, you could spawn a different instance for each app and run them all at the same time (don't know how iTunes Connect would handle that though).